# No response from eventNotification on Docusign

Tags: docusignapi, webhooks

Wanting to use a webhook for event notifications using the nodejs SDK, but not getting any pings to my endpoint and don't see any failures in the Connect portion of the DocuSign sandbox site.

Tried to use the code in this recipe: https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-node - but that is for an older version of the API and is broken.

Here is what I wound up doing:

```
    function setNotifications() {

    // and an eventNotification object which sets the parameters for
    // webhook notifications to us from the DocuSign platform
    var envelopeEvents = [];
    var envelopeEvent = new docusign.EnvelopeEvent();
    envelopeEvent.envelopeEventStatusCode = "sent";
    envelopeEvents.push(envelopeEvent);
    envelopeEvent = new docusign.EnvelopeEvent();
    envelopeEvent.envelopeEventStatusCode  = "delivered";
    envelopeEvents.push(envelopeEvent);
    envelopeEvent = new docusign.EnvelopeEvent();
    envelopeEvent.envelopeEventStatusCode = "completed";
    envelopeEvents.push(envelopeEvent);
    envelopeEvent = new docusign.EnvelopeEvent();
    envelopeEvent.envelopeEventStatusCode = "declined";
    envelopeEvents.push(envelopeEvent);
    envelopeEvent = new docusign.EnvelopeEvent();
    envelopeEvent.envelopeEventStatusCode = "voided";
    envelopeEvents.push(envelopeEvent);

    var recipientEvents = [];
    var recipientEvent = new docusign.RecipientEvent();
    recipientEvent.recipientEventStatusCode = "Sent";
    recipientEvents.push(recipientEvent);
    recipientEvent = new docusign.RecipientEvent();
    recipientEvent.recipientEventStatusCode = "Delivered";
    recipientEvents.push(recipientEvent);
    recipientEvent = new docusign.RecipientEvent();
    recipientEvent.recipientEventStatusCode = "Completed";
    recipientEvents.push(recipientEvent);
    recipientEvent = new docusign.RecipientEvent();
    recipientEvent.recipientEventStatusCode = "Declined";
    recipientEvents.push(recipientEvent);
    recipientEvent = new docusign.RecipientEvent();
    recipientEvent.recipientEventStatusCode = "AuthenticationFailed";
    recipientEvents.push(recipientEvent);
    recipientEvent = new docusign.RecipientEvent();
    recipientEvent.recipientEventStatusCode = "AutoResponded";
    recipientEvents.push(recipientEvent);

    var eventNotification = new docusign.EventNotification();
    eventNotification.url = "https://MY_PUBLICLY_OPEN_URL";
    eventNotification.loggingEnabled = "true";
    eventNotification.requireAcknowledgment = "false" ;
    eventNotification.useSoapInterface = "false";
    eventNotification.includeCertificateWithSoap = "false";
    eventNotification.signMessageWithX509Cert = "false";
    eventNotification.includeDocuments = "false";
    eventNotification.includeEnvelopeVoidReason = "true";
    eventNotification.includeTimeZone = "true";
    eventNotification.includeSenderAccountAsCustomField = "true";
    eventNotification.includeDocumentFields = "true";
    eventNotification.includeCertificateOfCompletion = "true";
    eventNotification.envelopeEvents = envelopeEvents;
    eventNotification.recipientEvents = recipientEvents;

    return eventNotification;
}

var envDef = new docusign.EnvelopeDefinition();
envDef.eventNotification = setNotifications();
```

EDIT -> here is the trace of the request from the DocuSign logs

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net:7802/restapi/v2/accounts/cc9747f3-0484-481c-8517-9a4cf0b23fc7/envelopes

TraceToken: bf38acf5-7cda-43ad-86e8-c89e36c5bb36
Timestamp: 2018-07-13T21:57:42.4983873Z

Content-Length: 1130
Content-Type: application/json


{
"envelopeId": "a uuid",
"uri": "/envelopes/a uuid",
"statusDateTime": "2018-07-13T21:57:42.1234037Z",
"status": "sent"
}
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer [omitted]
Host: demo.docusign.net
User-Agent: node-superagent/3.8.2
X-DocuSign-SDK: Node
X-Cnection: close
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1.2
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: nope
x-forwarded-for: nope

{"emailSubject":"a subject",
"templateId":"a uuid",
"templateRoles": [{"roleName":"Signee","name":"Chris Watkins","email":"an email"}],
"status":"sent",
"eventNotification":{
"url":"a url",
"loggingEnabled":"true",
"requireAcknowledgment":"false",
"useSoapInterface":"false",
"includeCertificateWithSoap":"false",
"signMessageWithX509Cert":"false",
"includeDocuments":"false",
"includeEnvelopeVoidReason":"true",
"includeTimeZone":"true",
"includeSenderAccountAsCustomField":"true",
"includeDocumentFields":"true",
"includeCertificateOfCompletion":"true",
"envelopeEvents":[
{"envelopeEventStatusCode":"Sent"},
{"envelopeEventStatusCode":"Delivered"}, 
{"envelopeEventStatusCode":"Completed"}, 
{"envelopeEventStatusCode":"Declined"}, 
{"envelopeEventStatusCode":"Voided"}],
"recipientEvents":
[
{"recipientEventStatusCode":"Sent"}, 
{"recipientEventStatusCode":"Delivered"}, 
{"recipientEventStatusCode":"Completed"}, 
{"recipientEventStatusCode":"Declined"}, 
{"recipientEventStatusCode":"AuthenticationFailed"}, 
{"recipientEventStatusCode":"AutoResponded"}]}}
201 Created
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: bf38acf5-7cda-43ad-86e8-c89e36c5bb36
```

The rest is working - docs are sent, and I can use the API to check on the envelope status (this is my backup). Any ideas? I am not sure how to capture the actual HTTP request that nodejs is sending out, but am happy to do so with instruction, if that's helpful.

Also, it would be very helpful to have updated documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Offhand, your code looks good.

Suggestions:

1. For testing purposes, start an Account-level Connect (webhook) subscription for your same server by using the Admin Tool (Connect section). If that works then your problem is somewhere in your code. If that doesn't work, then your problem is in your listener (your server), or elsewhere. One envelope can be covered by multiple Connect subscriptions so there is no need to change your envelope create code while testing.
2. Use the [API trace feature](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) to get a trace of your envelope create call and then update your question with the trace. There might be some issue that is causing the underlying evenNotification to be incorrect.
3. You are setting the envelope to "sent", yes? And the envelope is otherwise working?
4. Check the Connect logs (from the admin tool) to see if there are any messages. EventNotification logging goes to the Connect logs.

ps. Sorry about the example, I'm working to update all of them.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the trace. Since using Account-level Connect seems to be working for you, there is a problem with your eventNotification object settings. Things to check:

1. Does the `url` setting start with "https://whatever.com"? Only https is supported.
2. I recommend setting `requireAcknowledgment` to "true"

If there are still problems we can continue to investigate.

Comment: great suggestions. Using Account-level Connect, I see log entries (failures due to a bad SSL cert on my end). Not using Account-level Connect, I see neither entries nor failures. Added the trace to the question. Envelope is "sent" and the rest of the flow is working great. No worries about the samples - a big thanks for putting together the various SDKs and having recipes for the different platforms. It is much appreciated.